# Cannot access jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to add one more jsp page to project but can't find out how to bind a link to it. I have this project structure

[image]

I want access to admin.jsp.
But the only thing I achieved so far is open the people.jsp on admin link. In other cases, I get not found error.

This is web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/people/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is application context

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

How to handle this problem?

Comment: What link are you trying to use to reach admin.jsp?

Comment: what url do you enter on browser and what is the error you get?

Comment: this http://192.168.1.34:8080/message-board/admin.jsp or this http://192.168.1.34:8080/message-board/admin/ or http://192.168.1.34:8080/message-board/admin

Comment: and the working one is http://192.168.1.34:8080/message-board/people/

Comment: /people works obviously because it is the url pattern mapped to DispatcherServlet... What error do you get to see on hitting admin.jsp. I mean HTTP 404 Error?

Comment: by the way, what IDE is that you are using? Asking casually, it looks nice :)

Comment: if you want that spring servlet been dispatcher for de admin page you must change the url-patter of the servlet. Now it just works for any url like message-board/people...

Comment: This jet brains Idea ide

Comment: It's an empty page or pure text 'not found' or text like 'message-board/admin.jsp'

Comment: How exactly should I change it?

Answer (score 1):

use just `/*` in url pattern.it will work for all `.jsp` page